# ¿Cómo puedo sumar los valores de dos textbox y mostrarlos en un tercero?

Tags: c#, mysql

Buen dia, aquí pidiendo apoyo de nuevo, quisiera saber cómo puedo hacer que en un textbox me aparezca la suma de otros textbox, teniendo estos un valor que se asigna desde mi base de datos de mysql, anexo parte de mi código, mi variable declarada es: `float total=0;`

```
MySqlConnection conexion = new MySqlConnection();
                conexion.ConnectionString = "Server=127.0.0.1;Database=proyecto_final;Uid=root;Pwd=****;";
                conexion.Open();
                string consulta = string.Format("insert into ventas (ID,fecha,total,cajero) values (null,'{0}','{1}','{2}')", label3.Text, textBox1.Text, textBox3.Text);
                //MessageBox.Show(consulta);
                MySqlCommand x = new MySqlCommand(consulta, conexion);
                x.ExecuteNonQuery();//ejecuta la consulta

                comboBox6.Visible = true;
                label9.Visible = true;
                label1.Visible = true;
                textBox4.Visible = true;
                total = Convert.ToSingle(textBox1.Text);
                total = Convert.ToSingle(textBox5.Text + "precio") + Convert.ToSingle(textBox4.Text +"precio");
```

Si me pueden resolver ésta duda se los agradecería.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes declarar una variable de tipo int y asignarle el valor del resultado de hacer un int.Parse(TextBox). Ejemplo:

```
int total;

total = int.Parse(textBox5.Text) + int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
```

Luego solo sería cuestión de mostrarlo en el textbox nuevo:

```
textBoxTotal.Text = total.ToString();
```

Comment: aun asi no me aparece la suma en el textboxtotal, sigue apareciendo vacio :(

Comment: ¿Estás usando los eventos correctamente? Me refiero a si estás tratando de actualizar el text box dentro del evento correcto. Si estás intentando actualizarlo al momento de iniciar la aplicación y los text box que usas para hacer el cálculo están vacíos, entonces no se va a llenar con nada.

Comment: si no me equivoco, esas lineas de codigo las estoy poniendo en el evento que se crea del textboxtotal, para que el textboxtotal tome los valores de los otros dos, si estoy equivocado orientame un poco                                   private void textBox1_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {//TEXTBOXTOTAL
            total = int.Parse(textBox5.Text) + int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
            textBox1.Text = total.ToString();
        }

Comment: Ahí veo que el textbox total se llama "textBox1", pero que el evento que se está disparando es su propio TextChanged. Te recomendaría pasar ese código al evento de TextChanged de los otros dos text boxes, para que cuando cambie el número en cualquiera de los dos, el texto en el total se actualice.

Comment: Ya aparece un total pero...aun no suma solo me muestra el precio mayor EJ: si tengo un producto de 1000 y otro de 200, me mustra solo el precio de 1000,no suma, las lineas de codigo las he colocado en cada TextChanged y es lo unico que he podido conseguir